# What is the difference between hash-target and the previous hash?

Tags: hash, block-hash

Is the target that the requirements have to meet a number that is set by the network that is always the same, or is the target the hash from the previous block?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question: the target is not always the same number. For additional details read this https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target